Razorpay Payment Link Requires Phone Number Despite Providing Customer Details
I'm using Razorpay's Node.js SDK to create payment links. Although I am providing the customer details, including the phone number, every payment link still prompts the customer to input their phone number manually during payment.
Steps to Reproduce:

Use Razorpay's Node.js SDK to create a payment link.
Provide the customer object with valid details such as phone number,
email, and name.
Access the payment link generated.
Notice that the payment page still requests the phone number input.

Code
const Razorpay = require('razorpay');

const instance = new Razorpay({
  key_id: 'your_key_id',
  key_secret: 'your_key_secret',
});

const paymentLinkOptions = {
  amount: 5000, // Amount in smallest currency unit
  currency: 'INR',
  description: 'Test Payment',
  customer: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john.doe@example.com',
    contact: '+919876543210', // Phone number
  },
  notify: {
    sms: true,
    email: true,
  },
  callback_url: 'https://example.com/callback',
  callback_method: 'get',
};

instance.paymentLink.create(paymentLinkOptions)
  .then((paymentLink) => {
    console.log('Payment Link:', paymentLink);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error creating payment link:', error);
  });


"As per Razorpay's updated security policy, even if the customer's email address and phone number are provided while creating the Payment Link, these details are not auto-populated on the Checkout section of the Payment Link hosted page. The customer will have to enter these details manually while making the payment." Could this be the issue why you are being prompted for re-entry of phone number?

Is this same while creating an order and do a checkout?
